# No me funciona el boton al enviar formulario con php

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, submit

Quiero hacer un formulario con html y php que al apretar el botón enviar me mande el correo a mi cuenta, aparte, que me direccione a una página tipo "exito.html" donde diga un mensaje que el correo fue enviado satisfactoriamente, luego de eso, que dure 2 segundos en esa página y me regrese a la página del formulario. Con php, no me estaría funcionando, pero con la pagina "exito.html" con js si me funciona. Hay algo en form.php que no estaría haciendo bien y no logro encontrar el error. Si alguien me ayuda, se lo agradezco un montón.

```
<?php


$nombre = $_POST ['name'];
$apellido = $_POST ['lastname'];
$email = $_POST ['email'];
$mensaje = $_POST ['textarea'];



// Como me va a llegar a mi el cuerpo del mensaje al email //


$referencia = "Este mensaje fue enviado por el usuario: " . $nombre . $apellido "\r\n";
$referencia .= "Email del usuario: " . $email . "\r\n";
$referencia .= "Mensaje de usuario: " . $_POST ["textarea"] . "\r\n";
$referencia .= "Enviado el: " . date ("d/m/Y" , time() );


$destinatario = 'andresderin78@gmail.com'; // Email a donde va a llegar el mensaje //
$asunto = 'Este mensaje fue enviado desde la web'; // Asunto que me va a llegar al emaildesde la página //


mail($destinatario, $asunto , utf8_decode($referencia) , $header);

header('Location.exito.html');

?>



        <form action="form.php" method="POST">
        <div class="row g-3">
            <div class="col">
                <label for="name" class="form-label">Nombre</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Nombre" aria-label="First name">
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <label for="lastname" class="form-label">Apellido</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastname" name="lastname" placeholder="Apellido" aria-label="Last name">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="exampleFormControlInput1" class="form-label">Email</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1" name="email" placeholder="nombre@ejemplo.com">
          </div>
          <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1" class="form-label">Comentario</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" name="textarea" rows="3" placeholder="Escribe tu comntario"></textarea>
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="button">Enviar</button>
        </form>
```

Comment: La sintaxis de esta línea no es correcta: `header('Location.exito.html');`.  Aparte de eso, si la corriges y ejecutas, verás que nunca llegas a ver el formulario, porque siempre te mandará a exito.html antes de mostrarlo. Debes encerrar en un condicional todo el PHP previo al formulario y que se ejecute solo cuando reciba datos por POST.

Comment: Aún no eh llegado a esa parte de condicionales en mi curso de desarrollo web, para encerrar todo en PHP previo al formulario, me darías un tips como hacerlo o donde buscar una info que me ayude, gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Creo que hay varias cosas que se pueden mejorar en tu código y es posible que alguna de estas te esté dando problemas.

Para empezar con cosas fáciles:
Pasas el texto del textarea a una variable pero después no la vuelves a usar

```
$mensaje = $_POST ['textarea'];
.
$referencia .= "Mensaje de usuario: " . $_POST ["textarea"] . "\r\n";
```

En su lugar puedes usar:

```
$referencia .= "Mensaje de usuario: $mensaje \r\n";
```

Después tienes la linea de e-mail con un campo **header** que no es obligatorio y en el que tampoco le veo sentido en este caso:

```
mail($destinatario, $asunto , utf8_decode($referencia) , **$header**);
```

Además de esto, cada vez que ejecutas este archivo te manda el e-mail aunque esté todo vacio.
Deberías añadir lógica condicional para que no haga todo el proceso de setear variables y mandar e-mail si aún no has rellenado nada:

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
$nombre = $_POST ['name'];
.
$return = mail($destinatario, $asunto , utf8_decode($referencia));
}
```

Si has visto, he añadido una variable return a la devolución de la función mail().
Si la función devuelve 0 es que ha enviado el e-mail correctamente. Si devuelve 1 es que ha fallado.
Con eso podrías mostrar un mensaje de enviado con éxito. Algo como así:

```
   if ($mailReturn == true) {
      echo "<div id = \"success\">E-mail enviado con éxito</div>";
      } else {
        echo "<div id = \"fail\">E-mail cannot be sended.</div>";
      }
    }
```

Para finalizar, si queires que la web se recargue, puedes añadir un javascript en el punto que necesites. Podría ser como este:

```
<script LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
    var pagina="<?= $url ?>"
    function redireccionar()
    {
    location.href=pagina
    }
    setTimeout ("redireccionar()", 10);
</script>
```

donde "< ? = $url ? >" podria ser la que ya tienes creada arriba:

```
$url = form.php;
```

Yo lo he probado en local y con estos cambios me funciona bastante bien.

Comment: Hola, te agradezco que te hallas tomado el tiempo para responder y para corregirme los errores del código. Aún sigo sin poder lograr el objetivo deseado. Al apretar el boton enviar luego de llenar el formulario se me descarga el archivo de form.php, no me lleva a la página de "exito.html" donde tengoun mensaje de "gracias por dejar tu comentario, etc..." y que a los 2 segundos me redirecciones a la página anterior donde se encuentra el formulario.

Comment: el html como me dijiste que modificara.

Comment: Hola Andrés. El problema es que la lógica para mandar el e-mail está en el mismo archivo "form.php", por lo que abrir desde ese botón una página extra diciendo que se ha mandado correctamente no sería del todo real. Por eso en la función "if ($mailReturn == true) {" te devuelve un true o un false. Lo que podrías hacer es que al cargar la página form.php, si es success, te cargue un javascript de "window.onload = function ()": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19707236/show-popup-after-page-load

Answer (score 0):

Creo que no te funciona porque hay botones mal declarados en tu formulario, a parte de tener el botón submit mal declarado el cual no puede ser button de tag, tiene que ser un input de type="submit"

```
<?php


$nombre = $_POST ['name'];
$apellido = $_POST ['lastname'];
$email = $_POST ['email'];
$mensaje = $_POST ['textarea'];

// Como me va a llegar a mi el cuerpo del mensaje al email //

$referencia = "Este mensaje fue enviado por el usuario: " . $nombre . $apellido "\r\n";
$referencia .= "Email del usuario: " . $email . "\r\n";
$referencia .= "Mensaje de usuario: " . $_POST ["textarea"] . "\r\n";
$referencia .= "Enviado el: " . date ("d/m/Y" , time() );


$destinatario = 'andresderin78@gmail.com'; // Email a donde va a llegar el mensaje 
//
$asunto = 'Este mensaje fue enviado desde la web'; // Asunto que me va a llegar al emaildesde la página //


mail($destinatario, $asunto , utf8_decode($referencia) , $header);

header('Location.exito.html');

?>



    <form action="form.php" method="POST">
    <div class="row g-3">
        <div class="col">
            <label for="name" class="form-label">Nombre</label>
          <input type="textbox" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Nombre" aria-label="First name" />
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <label for="lastname" class="form-label">Apellido</label>
          <input type="textbox" class="form-control" id="lastname" name="lastname" placeholder="Apellido" aria-label="Last name" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="exampleFormControlInput1" class="form-label">Email</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1" name="email" placeholder="nombre@ejemplo.com" />
      </div>
      <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1" class="form-label">Comentario</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" name="textarea" rows="3" placeholder="Escribe tu comentario"></textarea>
      </div>
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="button" value="Enviar" />
    </form>
```